# ArgumentError: A copy of ApplicationController has been removed from the module tree but is still active

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using ActiveAdmin (with customized gemset for Rails 4) with Rails 4.0.0.rc2. Application also has custom-built authorization code based on railscasts [#385](http://railscasts.com/episodes/385-authorization-from-scratch-part-1) and [#386](http://railscasts.com/episodes/386-authorization-from-scratch-part-2).

When I change something in a ActiveAdmin resource file and try to refresh the browser page, I get this error at the `current_permission` method:

> **ArgumentError at /admin/courses**
>
> **A copy of ApplicationController has been removed from the module tree but is still active!**

If I try a refresh again, I get:

> **Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Permissions**

I think this problem has something to do with autoloading of classes in development mode, after a change in the source file. I have seen similar problem posts, but they are for rails 2.3.x. Also, the solution seems to be specifying `unloadable` in the controller throwing this error, but I am not sure where to put in this snippet in ActiveAdmin.

This might not have anything to do with ActiveAdmin either. It might be about how Permissions class has been built and its usage within Application Controller. If I add a `skip_before_filter :authorize` in the ActiveAdmin resource class, this error vanishes.

ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :authorize

  delegate :allow_action?, to: :current_permission
  helper_method :allow_action?

  delegate :allow_param?, to: :current_permission
  helper_method :allow_param?

  private
    def current_permission
      @current_permission ||= Permissions.permission_for(current_user)
    end

    def current_resource
      nil
    end

    def authorize
      if current_permission.allow_action?(params[:controller], params[:action], current_resource)
        current_permission.permit_params! params
      else
        redirect_to root_url, alert: "Not authorized."
      end
    end
end
```

Permissions.rb:

```
module Permissions
  def self.permission_for(user)
    if user.nil?
      GuestPermission.new
    elsif user.admin?
      AdminPermission.new(user)
    else
      UserPermission.new(user)
    end
  end
end
```

admin/courses.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Course do
  index do
    column :name
    column :description
    column :duration
    column :status
    column :price
    default_actions
  end

  filter :discipline
  filter :level
  filter :lessons
  filter :name
  filter :status
end
```

Gemfile (relevant lines):

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc2'

# Use puma as the app server
gem 'puma'

# Administration - Temporary github refs until rails 4 compatible releases
gem 'responders',          github: 'plataformatec/responders'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'
gem 'ransack',             github: 'ernie/ransack',            branch: 'rails-4'
gem 'activeadmin',         github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'formtastic',          github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'
```

ArgumentError:

```
ArgumentError - A copy of ApplicationController has been removed from the module tree but is still active!:
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:445:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
  rspec-core (2.13.1) lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:24:in `const_missing'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:17:in `current_permission'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:25:in `authorize'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:417:in `_run__1040990970961152968__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.4.122) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:12:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.4.122) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:22:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.4.122) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:16:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.4.122) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:28:in `call'
  meta_request (0.2.7) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.1.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
  meta_request (0.2.7) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
  meta_request (0.2.7) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2183739952227501342__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  puma (2.1.1) lib/puma/server.rb:369:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.1.1) lib/puma/server.rb:246:in `process_client'
  puma (2.1.1) lib/puma/server.rb:145:in `block in run'
  puma (2.1.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

RuntimeError: Circular Dependency:

```
RuntimeError - Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Permissions:
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:460:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
  rspec-core (2.13.1) lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:24:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:686:in `remove_constant'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:516:in `block in remove_unloadable_constants!'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:516:in `remove_unloadable_constants!'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:300:in `clear'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Finisher>'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:105:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Finisher>'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:377:in `_run__2753119820186226816__prepare__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:62:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  puma (2.1.1) lib/puma/server.rb:369:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.1.1) lib/puma/server.rb:246:in `process_client'
  puma (2.1.1) lib/puma/server.rb:145:in `block in run'
  puma (2.1.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Any clue will help.
Let me know if you need to view other code snippets in the application.

Comment: See also https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/5104

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why this is happening, but I found a workaound. Change this:

```
def current_permission
  @current_permission ||= Permissions.permission_for(current_user)
end
```

To this:

```
def current_permission
  @current_permission ||= ::Permissions.permission_for(current_user)
end
```

The error is raised [at this point in ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375d9a0a7fb329b0fbbd75a13e93e53a00520587/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb#L444-L446):

```
# Load the constant named +const_name+ which is missing from +from_mod+. If
# it is not possible to load the constant into from_mod, try its parent
# module using +const_missing+.
def load_missing_constant(from_mod, const_name)
  log_call from_mod, const_name

  unless qualified_const_defined?(from_mod.name) && Inflector.constantize(from_mod.name).equal?(from_mod)
    raise ArgumentError, "A copy of #{from_mod} has been removed from the module tree but is still active!"
  end
  # ...
end
```

The problem only occurs when you don't fully qualify the constant name, so Rails tries looking it up in the `ApplicationController` namespace.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I had an obscure circular reference. The `::` solved the issue. No more having to restart Rails every time I edit a file.

Comment: I also had this problem with a very simple case where I referenced a class name in a controller file OUTSIDE the controller, and then inside a controller method.  Adding the fully qualified name (i.e. `::User`) in all references fixed the problem!

Comment: Prepending the `::` to referenced classes in my `ApplicationController` solved my issue too!

Answer (score 147):

For future visitors, I thought I'd provide some clarification on the original problem even though the question is pretty old and there is already an accepted answer.

The `ArgumentError: A copy of X has been removed from the module tree but is still active` is raised when you are trying to access an automatically reloaded class (in app directory) from one that is not automatically reloaded (in lib directory).

Comment: Sweet. That is the best explaination I have found on this problem that occationally has haunted me. Took 30 seconds to fix now I know what the problem was. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah you are right. Can you suggest here how to fix this problem.

Comment: This is an exaplanation of why it happens, but it is not an answer. This should have been added as a comment to original question.

Comment: If you are in the console, exit and then reopen the console. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why this occurs.  It would be great to hear a generalized solution to this.  Also exiting/re-opening the console as @Joseph Gill has suggested is not a solution here since this can occur in the natural request cycle.

Comment: **Rails Console:** for those encountering the same problem: got this error on Rails console after `reload!`having changed a Model file. I had to exit the console then enter again.

Comment: I'm getting the error in question for Api::V1, but the only file I have in lib is application_responder.rb. Do you mean active_support is trying to access something in Api::V1?

Answer (score 6):

In you development.rb temporarily try putting

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This is not production stable solution.

Comment: Ya agreed. I didn't mention this explicitly but i wrote temporarily for that reason.

Comment: @SimonFranzen In 99% of cases you're going to wish to cache classes so it's incorrect to say this is not production stable. It is, nonetheless, a little hacky.

Comment: Hey @Ger, thanks for the response. Ok to sum it up.
1. to put temporarily config.cache_class = true in your development.rb does not solve the problem of this topic (maybe for vatsal with his current gem-stack, with his code of the project) 
2. when you have the error like this (and I had it in a production system) this answer is still not correct, because in the production.rb you should always cache your classes

Comment: @SimonFranzen I was probably being too pedantic :) I agree with your points, my point was that its totally safe/expected to have config.cache_classes = true in Production.

Comment: This is not what we want in development environment.

Answer (score 3):

I am not using ActiveAdmin, but I just experienced a circular dependency with ApplicationController.

The problem was a helper module was declared improperly:

```
app/helpers/home_helper.rb
```

was declared with:

```
module StaticHelper
```

After fixing this, everything was peachy. I did not research why this happened and Rails didn't return a more intelligent error message.

Answer (score 2):

You can try put this line in your `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`:

In Rails <= 4:

```
 config.skip_before_filter :load_footer_variables
```

In Rails >= 5

```
config.skip_before_action :load_footer_variables
```

Like suggested [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2334#issuecomment-40253691).

Comment: Indeed, in Rails 5 this would be:
skip_before_action

Answer (score -1):

If you have this problem in console, simply close console instead of reload! command as this happens due to automatically reloaded modules being run inside console  without being fully reloaded.