# Rails: A copy of MetricBase has been removed from the module tree but is still active

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem with my first ruby and rails application. When developing I have recently come across this error and not been able to solve it: `A copy of MetricBase has been removed from the module tree but is still active`. That happens when I make changes to the file, or a related file. It is resolved by restarting the server but that is quite inconvenient. So I would appreciate any help. Also regarding any wrong use of rails.

For context: I have some data in my database which I would like to analyze. For this I thought of the below structure.

[image: The call structure of the Metrics System]

1. The controller calls the manager
2. The manager has a list of suitable Metrics, all extending from MetricBase, which has common functions for creating the actual object
3. The manager calls each Metric-Class (e.g. ResourceStats)
4. The Metric-Class (e.g. ResourceStats) does some calculations etc. and then calls a method in the parent class
5. The parent class (MetricBase) creates a Metric-Model

At this point the error occurs, directly after entering `make_metric_model`:

```
class MetricBase
  def initialize(id, resource)
    @id = id
    @resource = resource
    @metrics = []
  end

  def make_metric_model(name, desc, value)
    # here the error is thrown
    metric = Metric.where({ metric_id: @id, name: name }).first 

    metric = Metric.new if metric.nil?

    metric.metric_id = @id
    metric.name = name
    metric.description = desc
    metric.value = value
    metric.resource = @resource

    @metrics.push(metric)
  end

  def get_metrics
    return @metrics
  end
end
```

The error trace

```
ArgumentError - A copy of MetricBase has been removed from the module tree but is still active!:
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:445:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
  app/models/metric_base.rb:9:in `make_metric_model'
  app/models/resource_stats.rb:11:in `analyze'
  app/models/metrics_manager.rb:20:in `block in run_all_metrics'
  app/models/metrics_manager.rb:11:in `run_all_metrics'
  app/controllers/metrics_controller.rb:12:in `run'
```

I have tried adding `::` before `Metric` as suggested in another question, but the same thing happens. Note that I come from a background of C++, Java and PHP.

I am using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.

Any help or tips are greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what the original issue is/was. A workaround was to use zeus and kill and restart the server after an edit.

A better solution I am now using is putting the classes in a `module Metrics` and it works.

Comment: where you able to get zeus to automatically restart the server after an edit? Or did you have to do it manually yourself?

Comment: Perhaps this answer might explain what you were running into, where not all files are automatically reloaded in the dev environment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23008837/149503