# Circular dependency issue Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, clockwork

So I have a file in the `lib` directory. At the top of that file, I include the following:

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
```

Whenever I include that require, I get the following error message:

```
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant AdminUser (RuntimeError)
```

In context:

```
/Users/ahcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:461:in `load_missing_constant': Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant AdminUser (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/ahcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/ahcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/Web Applications/main-site/app/admin/admin_user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here's the definition of the AdminUser class as generated by `activeadmin`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  index do
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :last_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    default_actions
  end

  filter :email

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end
  controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit admin_user: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you give some more context of the problem. Whats the definition of `AdminUser` class?

Comment: Also, I guess the actual definition of the AdminUser class is in `activeadmin` library?

Comment: Alright, so, I wound up just changing the name of `admin_user.rb` to `admin_user1.rb`. However, it does seem like a v hacky fix and I'm not sure at this point as to whether it will break `activeadmin`

Comment: It might not be an activeadmin issue at all.. See https://github.com/flyerhzm/switch_user/issues/34

Answer (score 2):

This might not be an `activeadmin` issue directly. Several gems broke in some versions of rails 4(Circular dependency issue) due to call to `unloadable`. So, this might be from some other gem you might be using.

References:

https://github.com/flyerhzm/switch_user/issues/34

https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage/issues/68

https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/101 (See last comment by Dan)

Comment: This link might be further useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561697/argumenterror-a-copy-of-applicationcontroller-has-been-removed-from-the-module