# Active Admin: A copy of the applicationController has been removed but is still active

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, model, activeadmin

Stack overflow - I've recently migrated to Active Admin because I needed a quick way to build a solid Admin backend - Unfortunately I am not able to totally make heads or tails of this error.

I assume it has something to do with Action Cable & Active Admin due to the fact that it's being called by my conversations controller but I haven't been able to see what's actually stopping it from working -> mind you recently I was trying to switch the devise registration over to a modal (i.e have the signup be a popup that is triggered on clicking signup/login)  but that hadn't worked out how I expected so I set it the way it was.

This issue seems to persist when I try to actually log in to the admin dashboard.

A copy of ApplicationController has been removed from the module tree 
but is still active!

```
Extracted source (around line #23):

  def load_conversations
  @conversations = Conversation.all
  end

  def load_messages
```

This is where the error is coming up. I do not know where to start - P.s. I had devise going with the admin role as a boolean (I.e we could set admin to true for regular users) before I discovered Active Admin - is there anything I should do with that?.

Comment: Did you try stopping your server, doing `spring stop`, and then restarting your server?

Comment: OOo I didn't know about the command spring stop I'll try that first! thanks

Update: It didn't do anything for me - still getting the 'a copy has been removed ' error.

Comment: Did you look [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2334) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561697/argumenterror-a-copy-of-applicationcontroller-has-been-removed-from-the-module?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)? It seems, if the error is coming at `Conversation`, that you may need to do `::Conversation`.