# ArgumentError (A copy of Api::V1 has been removed from the module tree but is still active!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I have been struggling with this problem for days now. I have an app for which I am building some APIs and the above mentioned error always crashes my app when running for the first time. The error vanishes on reloading the app but it's annoying none the less. Here are some similar questions asked about this error:

[A copy of xxx has been removed from the module tree but is still active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636334/a-copy-of-xxx-has-been-removed-from-the-module-tree-but-is-still-active)

[ArgumentError: A copy of ApplicationController has been removed from the module tree but is still active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561697/argumenterror-a-copy-of-applicationcontroller-has-been-removed-from-the-module)

These both links don't address the issue I'm facing. Here's the complete stack trace:

```
ArgumentError (A copy of Api::V1 has been removed from the module tree but is still active!):
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:202:in `const_missing'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:271:in `const_get'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:271:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `each'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `inject'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `constantize'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:582:in `get'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:613:in `constantize'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:85:in `controller_class_for'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:99:in `binary_params_for?'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:90:in `set_binary_encoding'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:67:in `path_parameters='
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:48:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
bullet (5.7.5) lib/bullet/rack.rb:14:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
airbrake (7.3.0) lib/airbrake/rack/middleware.rb:52:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.6.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.6.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.6.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.6.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rack-mini-profiler (1.0.0) lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:285:in `call'
webpacker (3.4.3) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:18:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.4) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:632:in `handle_request'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `block in run'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the stack trace suggests, this is a dependancy clash of the app with ActiveSupport. I recommend using the gem [bootsnap](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap). Bootsnap overrides `ActiveSupport::Dependencies` which is causing the issue in the first place. It also improves the app's load time which is actually what it is designed for. From [Bootsnap](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap#how-does-this-work) documentation:

> ActiveSupport::Dependencies.{autoloadable_module?,load_missing_constant,depend_on} are overridden to eliminate scans of ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths.

Comment: Resurrecting this because this issue is now being seen in an app following all of the instructions in the bootsnap gem.

You appear to have solved this by digging. Any insights you can share?

Comment: @DerrellDurrett I am sorry. This was a long time ago and just using bootsnap solved my problem. I haven't run into this problem ever since. May be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636334/a-copy-of-xxx-has-been-removed-from-the-module-tree-but-is-still-active can help.

Comment: That's likely it, though the specifics of circular dependencies are likely different. If it continues to be a problem, I guess I know what to look for....